# How to get full url and send to other js page using node express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to access **token** variable in another page(api.js), how can I use? 
**index.js**

```
  var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();                
        router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        var token = req.url;
        });       
    module.exports = router;
    module.exports.token1 = token;
```

**api.js**  [ I want to use token variable in api.js, like this sessionId: requestd.token1  ]

```
var apiai = require('apiai');
var requestd  = require('./index');
var app = apiai('-my-api-key');
var getRes = function(query) {
  var request = app.textRequest(query, {
      sessionId: requestd.token1
  });
const responseFromAPI = new Promise(
        function (resolve, reject) {
request.on('error', function(error) {
    reject(error);
});
request.on('response', function(response) {

resolve(response);
});
});
request.end();
return responseFromAPI;
};
module.exports = {getRes}
```

Comment: Is the path `requestd = require('index.js')` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();                
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        require('./api').get(req ,res) // Be sure your path is correct
    });       
module.exports = router;
```

**api.js**

```
var api = {
    get: function(req, res){
        var token = req.url;
        console.log(toaken);
    }
}
module.exports = api
```

Comment: Got this Error    
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:369:11)

Comment: That is not an error from this code. Please provide all of your code.

Comment: Have you tried my code? and what is the error? or is it that error in the first comment?

Comment: the code doesn't send any responses. it shouldn't have that error. you must have something more than just the code that I posted.

Comment: its chatbot application and i am using google dialogflow as a service so i want to get userid from url and send to sessionId(api.js)

Comment: the error occurs from sending multiple responses; therefore, it is not related to this "access variable from another file" thing. Make sure you don't send multiple responses.

Comment: my app main file is app.js that is running, can u help me that how can i find userid from url on api.js page

Answer (score 0):

please update require file statement `var requestd  = require('./index.js');`
and also define "token" variable before this statement `module.exports.token1 = token;`